# \\s not working with java regex

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to match a pattern of phone numbers like-:

1234567890

123-456-7890

123.456.7890

123 456 7890

This code is working fine for first three patterns. When I tried to work out on space with `\\s`, it is throwing a run time exception-:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal character range near index 12

\A\d{3}([.-\s]?)\d{3}\1\d{4}\Z
            ^

    at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:1924)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.range(Pattern.java:2594)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.clazz(Pattern.java:2507)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:2030)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:1964)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.group0(Pattern.java:2854)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:2018)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:1964)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1665)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:1337)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1022)
    at Regex13.main(Regex13.java:11)
```

I've also tried unicode pattern \u0020 and hexadecimal pattern \0x20 but still things are not working out.

```
//validating phone numbers
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
public class Regex13
{
    public static void main(String ...arg)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter phone number:");
        String phoneNumber=new java.util.Scanner(System.in).next();
        String patt="\\A\\d{3}([.-\\s]?)\\d{3}\\1\\d{4}\\Z";
        Pattern p=Pattern.compile(patt);
        Matcher m=p.matcher(phoneNumber);
        if(m.find())
            System.out.println("Valid phone number!!");
        else
            System.out.println("Invalid phone number!!");
    }
}
```

What can be the possible solution for this??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually problem lies in other place. Parser interpreting `[.-\\s]` as range. For instance same happens for `[a-z]`, but the first one is invalid. Solve this by simply re-ordering `[-.\\s]`

Comment: Alternatively, escaping the `-` will work as well: `[.\\-\\s]`